# Probabilities of a rigged coin

Tags: probability

Suppose you have a rigged coin that gives a higher probability of coming up heads.

a) On average, how many times do you have to toss the coin to get the first head?

b) How many tosses do you have to make to get 2 heads in a row?

c) How many tosses do you have to make to get n heads in a row?

I don't know how to start with this one, I mean, it's  easier when we have a 50/50 chance (or maybe a fixed probability), but I don't know what I have to consider if 0.5 < P < 1

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Let $\mathbb{P}(H)=p\in(\frac{1}{2},1]$. Let $N$ be the number of tosses up to and including the first heads. Now consider partitioning on the first toss.